# How to configure my SQLite database with my Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel-5, sqlite

I had created a database  named **Grocs.db** using  **sqlite3** .The path of the database is **C:\Sqlite\Grocs.db**.

- How can I configure this **Grocs.db** database into my Laravel Project?
- Is it fine to simply move this database to the  my laravel project's database folder? i.e. to the path  **mylaravelproject/database** ?
- If it is done by the above method, then what about the extension **.db**? Should I have to change the extension from  **Grocs.db** to **Grocs.sqlite**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the database connection in the `./.env` file of the application.

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=/absolute/path/to/database.sqlite
```

[The Laravel database documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database) contains the 'SQLite Configuration' section.

Comment: its worked!  maybe beginners are little bit confused with the term 'absolute path'.Here I used the full path where the database resides.i.e, "C:\Sqlite\grocs.sqlite".

Comment: and I have to change my database name from Grocs.db to Grocs.sqlite.. 

Comment: yeah... it makes no differnece in changing the 'file ending ' of a database.